# I can't install eslint 5.6.0 or run my project

Tags: reactjs, npm, eslint

I'm trying to run my project in react, however when trying to run a warning appears:

```
> crud2@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start


There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "eslint": "5.6.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of eslint was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\Jose Djalma\node_modules\eslint (version: 8.28.0)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if C:\Users\Jose Djalma\node_modules\eslint is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls eslint in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed eslint.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!
```

I've already tried using the commands requested with `npm`, `yarn`, I've already removed node_modles in the end, I've tried to do a lot, so I'm trying to install the `5.6.0` version of `eslint`, using the command `yarn add eslint@5.6.0`, also tried `npm i eslint@5.6.0`. But for some reason when I do any of these commands the version of eslint.is `8.28.0`, which doesn't make sense to me, can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try to remove `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` and install the packages all again?

Comment: yes, I just tried that and it keeps giving the same error, in fact, now it asks me to install version 5.12.0, however whenever I do the command npm i eslint@5.12.0 or yarn add eslint@5.12.0 it does not install

Comment: the parts referring to the eslint are like this:
  ` "dependencies": {[...] "eslint": "5.12.0", [...]`
and:

        "devDependencies": {
            "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
            "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
            "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^8.0.3",
            "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
            "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.0",
            "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0.0",
            "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
            "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    [...]
          },

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format the code in the comments

Comment: I tried both commands (I tried running before running the other one) and the problem persists

Comment: I removed the node_modules and redid the process again (although I had done it before) and now it works, thanks anyway for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` and install the packages all again with `yarn` or `npm i` after removing the `node_modules` folder by `rm -rf node_modules`.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm yarn.lock
yarn
```

Or

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm i
```

To install the exact version of `eslint`, you can run `npm i --save --save-exact eslint@5.12.0` or `yarn add --exact eslint@5.12.0`

Hope it helps!